# Prevent child rerenders when parent state is changed?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

This is a simplified version of my problem

https://codesandbox.io/s/withered-night-6jbgft

```
import React, { useState, useCallback } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

const Box = React.memo(({ c, i, handleClick }) => {
  return (
    <div
      className="box"
      style={{ background: c }}
      onClick={() => handleClick(i)}
    ></div>
  );
});

export default function App() {
  const COUNT_BOXES = 250;
  const [colour, setColour] = useState("#00ff00");
  const [boxes, setBoxes] = useState(Array(COUNT_BOXES).fill("#ff00ff"));

  const changeColour = useCallback(
    (i) => {
      setBoxes((prevBoxes) => {
        prevBoxes[i] = colour;
        return [...prevBoxes];
      });
    },
    [colour]
  );

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        type="color"
        value={colour}
        onChange={(e) => setColour(e.target.value)}
      />
      Change colour
      <div className="wrapper">
        {boxes.map((c, i) => (
          <Box key={i} c={c} i={i} handleClick={changeColour} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I have a series of components that can be interacted with (the boxes). When you click a box, it changes colour. The colour it gets changed to is another piece of state in the parent component. The current implementation means that when the `colour` state changes, then `useCallback` creates a new function for `changeColour`, which is passed to every box. So every box rerenders.

How can I refactor this so that every box doesn't need to rerender when the parent colour changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility would be to store the parent's `changeColour` function inside a ref, so that the reference is stable. It's not the usual React way of doing things, but it works.

```js
const { useState, useCallback, useEffect } = React;

const Box = React.memo(({ c, i, handleClickRef }) => {
  console.log('render');
  return (
    <div
      className="box"
      style={{ background: c }}
      onClick={() => handleClickRef.current(i)}
    ></div>
  );
});

function App() {
  console.log('app rendering');
  const COUNT_BOXES = 250;
  const [colour, setColour] = useState("#00ff00");
  const [boxes, setBoxes] = useState(Array(COUNT_BOXES).fill("#ff00ff"));
  const changeColourRef = React.useRef();
  const changeColour = useCallback(
    (i) => {
      setBoxes((prevBoxes) => {
        prevBoxes[i] = colour;
        return [...prevBoxes];
      });
    },
    [colour]
  );
  useEffect(() => {
    changeColourRef.current = changeColour;
  }, [colour]);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        type="color"
        value={colour}
        onChange={(e) => setColour(e.target.value)}
      />
      Change colour
      <div className="wrapper">
        {boxes.map((c, i) => (
          <Box key={i} c={c} i={i} handleClickRef={changeColourRef} />
        ))}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}


ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector('.react')).render(<App />);
```

```css
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 30px;
}
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex: 0 0 40px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.box {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

It would be nicer if you could just let the children re-render - it usually won't be a problem (and if it is a problem, usually it's fixable by tweaking your code, while continuing to let the component re-render).

Comment: Amazing - thank you. "It's not the usual React way of doing things" - what are the drawbacks of doing this? I'd love to let them render, but in practise there can be up to 90k of these so it gets very sluggish

Comment: Using refs can make values that depend on other values a bit harder to formulate. Refs are fundamentally mutable objects, but the React philosophy is to have everything flow from state instead, and not to mutate when possible. But if the nature of the app is that doing things the natural way is just too computationally expensive, then you'll have to figure out some other way, like this one, even if it's odd.

Comment: For folks visiting later, I've found this related article which was helpful https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2020/11/react-useref-hook/ . So now I can `use const colour = React.useRef("#00ff00");`